# Network failure when device in Doze Mode

Tags: android, pjsip, android-doze, android-doze-and-standby

I have a doubt regarding Doze Mode. In Doze mode, when we receive a GCM notification, how long the app will have access to network services? Can we acquire partial wakelock to prevent entering into doze mode again? How to check the logs whether the device is entering doze mode or exiting doze mode?

In my app, I have a pjsip native library which does SRV lookup for SIP Registration, when we receive GCM Notification. The Device is woken up when we receive a GCM notification but when we try to SRV lookup, we are getting "Operation not Permitted" error.

This issue happens only in Doze mode

Can somebody please help

Comment: Did you get any way to solve it?